# Как сделать дизайн 404 страницы?

Tags: python, html, http-status-code-404

Как сделать что бы 404 страница выглядела не по умолчанию, а как ты хочешь? Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается с помощью backend, к примеру на flask(python), если вас интересует конкретная библиотека или конкретный язык вам стоит об этом написать подробнее.

Comment: Расскажу подробнее: при получении ошибки 404, flask перенаправит в конкретный документ html, который как раз пишете вы

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Поставитьте галочку если ответ верный

Comment: да, я  только сейчас смог

Answer (score 4):

Нужно на стороне сервера создать отслеживание HTTP-кода 404.
На фреймворке Flask для Python выглядит как-то так:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def error404(error):
    return render_template('error404.html')#название .html файла и функции может быть любым, но обязательно в аргументы функции ставьте аргумент 'error'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```